# What is the success rate of NASA launches?

Tags: launch, nasa

What is the success rate of NASA launches since it was founded in 1958? I'd appreciate a decade by decade statistic. By successful I mean a successful launch into space and release of payload (if any). It's irrelevant if the payload itself fails later.

**Edit:** IOW, the Challenger disaster should be considered a failure while Columbia, *within this scope*, should be considered a success as disaster struck only during re-entry. I'm only interested in official NASA launches into space. Sounding Rockets, ICBMs, etc. can be excused from this question.

Comment: Taking just the launch vehicle (LV) success rates into account (not counting payload success rate), the best data can probably be collated through [Space Launch Report All-Time Launcher Results Summary](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/logsum.html). Some numbers according to other sources are [85% for 1958-74 time period](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-4211/ch10-5.htm) and [94% for 1989-98 time period](http://weboflife.nasa.gov/shuttle/nexgen/Bayesian_launcher_reliability.htm), but overall figures would depend on which LVs you actually count, and the question is rather vague regarding that. ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what kind of missions you are talking about? Just ones where the purpose was a routine launch of a payload or ones where the purpose was to test an LV system? What counts as a failure? Does it have to blow up before it's considered a failure or is it a fail if it gets aborted / postponed?

Comment: Technically speaking, the Columbia disaster was actually a result of an insulation separation and collision with the vehicle *during launch*.

Comment: You'd need to define "NASA launch". Is that just NASA-designed vehicles? Does it include commercial vehicles with NASA payloads? Does it include Soyuz launches that NASA paid for?

Answer (score 10):

According to this [site](http://www.spaceref.com/news/viewpr.html?pid=8176)

> the Delta II has successfully launched more than 190 NASA missions and maintains a **98 percent success rate**.

*success rate of [SHUTTLE](http://www.braeunig.us/space/specs/shuttle.htm) is **98.25%** to end-2005*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm having a hard time just sorting out NASA, but here's the statistics for every launch, using the source information found [here](http://planet4589.org/space/log/launchlog.txt). This gives the following breakdown, by decade

- 1950's 43.6%
- 1960's 85.1%
- 1970's 93.5%
- 1980's 96.0%
- 1990's 93.9%
- 2000's 94.7%
- 2010's 94.7%

Note the list was last updated Oct 8, 2015.

Comment: Launch success rates should be ronded to one or zero digits behind the the point.

Comment: Done. In the future, feel free to propose an edit by clicking on the edit button.